# Static functions in Symfony Entities, while passing EntityManagerInterface?

Tags: symfony, design-patterns, doctrine

I'm currently designing my own service using Symfony, Doctrine and MySQL. I have several Entities, which allow fast database interaction. The project is for creating and managing sports tournaments with group system and finals. For this I for example have the `Matches.php` Entity, which has the normal Entity structure. From there on I added several static and non-static functions, related to the `Matches` entity. Here are 2 examples:

```
// Non-static function for getting TeamB's points. 
public function getPointsTeamB(): int
{
    $score = $this->getScore();
    if($score["team_a"] < $score["team_b"]) return 3;
    if($score["team_a"] == $score["team_b"]) return 1;
    return 0;
}

// Static function to getting the next games in the match plan.
public static function getNext(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, int $amount): array
{
return $entityManager->getRepository(Matches::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder("m")
    ->select("m.id", "IDENTITY(m.team_a) AS team_a", "IDENTITY(m.team_b) AS team_b", "m.started_at", "m.ended_at", "m.paused_at", "m.paused_for")
    ->where("m.started_at is NULL AND m.ended_at is NULL")
    ->orderBy("m.id", "ASC")
    ->setMaxResults($amount)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
}
```

I access these functions for example here:

```
#[Route('/ajax/matches/get_next/{amount}', name: 'app_ajax_match_get_next', requirements: ['match_id' => '\d+'], methods: ["GET"])]
    public function app_ajax_match_get_next(int $amount, RequestStack $requestStack, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $req = RequirementsCheck::create($requestStack, $entityManager, permissions: [Permission::VIEW_DASHBOARD]);
        if(!$req->isAllowed()) return $req->getResponse();
        $matches = Matches::getNext($entityManager, $amount);
        return new JsonResponse(APISerializer::serializeDoctrineObjects($matches, $entityManager));
    }
```

As you can see I just use call the function using `Matches::getNext()`

Now I was talking to someone, who told me that I should rewrite my code because of this 'bad habit'. As you can see I pass the EntityManagerInterface whenever needed in the function. They said that Entities should primarily represent the data and state of an object and should not be tightly coupled with database-specific operations and that there will be Testing and Reusability issues. Is that true and if yes, where should I put these functions? Should I rewrite my code or just change my design next time?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: He is correct, It is bad practice to use the entity manager in your entities. You could easily refactor your code and use a new service to manage matches and score. You could then autowire the entity manager to your new service and autowire your new service to your controller.

Comment: Also this question would fit the codereview stackexchange instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: Those sorts of functions would typically be located in your MatchesRepository.  Your getNext query seems very strange. And does getNext really return a repository? By the way I have written these sorts of tournament things.  You probably want to make a separate service to determine team standings including the points per game type stuff.  You will need it for the tie breaking code.

Comment: @DylanKAS thanks for the answer. I've taken the time to read into services and refactored the most used and most important functions into services that I can autowire now. It doesn't seem to make it easier programming wise, but probably way more efficient. I'll try reading more into the docs before writing my code.